# exclude a folder from expressjs routing

Tags: javascript, node.js, backbone.js, express

On my expressjs app, public assets are loaded in this way:

```
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
```

And then I redirect all requests to the index, to handle every path with *Backbone*

```
app.get('*', routes.index);
```

Why the */public* folder is redirect too?

Also if i try to add *'/public'* as a first argument, it doesn't work:

```
app.use('/public', express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After you placed the static router before `app.router`, express will attempt to serve requests first by matching a file from the static folder (`public`), if there's no match, it will pass it to `routes.index` as the following rule matches everything;

```
app.get('*', routes.index);
```

Also, to match any file from `public` dir, you need not use `/public/` in the request url.

For example to fetch `public/images/icon.png` or `public/js/scripts.js`, you will only need to access `/images/icon.png` or `/js/scripts.js`. If you invoke a `/public` request, it will not match anything in static dir, and pass the request on to `routes.index`.

Hope it helps.

Comment: thanks for stopping by to give a good clarification and explanation of the problem, even if I already found the solution.

Comment: You can decide order of `static` and `router` based on requests. If you're going to serve more requests from app routes and little or no static ones, place router ahead of static. Generally in web apps (lots of images, js, css files), I prefer putting static ahead of router. So that request for these files do not pass through all application routes (via router) in vain, ending up being server from file system.

Answer (score 2):

For anyone who get any problem related to static files serving:

Before evaluating possible solutions to the problem, be sure to define *express.static* **before** the *app.use(app.router)*.

I found lots of examples online: sometimes its defined below, sometimes not.
Putting it first solved all my problems.

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname + '/public')))
app.use(app.router)
```